# Is PHP curl request on server side visible to user / browser

Tags: php, curl

This question might sound stupid but is a CURL request made in PHP code on server, visible to a visitor/user or the browser. Can the user debug the contents of the curl request. I tried to debug it in chrome but it was not visible and this answer is not available on the internet. Hence, I am asking it here.

Comment: No it isn'tㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: No, it's like any other server side code, it cannot be seen by the end user. And unless they have a separate way to sniff the server's network traffic they can't see what is being transmitted either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a visitor to your site cannot see what is happening in the server side code. It may not even be apparent to them that you're making a server side request to another site.

You should ensure your PHP code is making use of the `curl_error()` function to determine what happened with the request and assist with your debugging.